# Django update or delete own made data only

Tags: django

Trying to add permissions on a django form. User created own instances. That data only updatable/deletable if the creator trying to do action. I'm using generic updateview. Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide your current code? Permissions to update/delete are created automatically for each model.

Comment: Thanks for your valueable comment. Got django guardian. It is the best solution what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in settings.py

```
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your valueable comment. Got django guardian. It is the best solution what I needed.